# Commutators involving $\Box$ and $\Box^{-1}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differentiation

How to determine the followings:

$$[\Box,\frac{1}{\Box}]\mathcal{O}=?$$

$$[\nabla,\frac{1}{\nabla}]\mathcal{O}=?$$

$$[\nabla^2,\frac{1}{\nabla^2}]\mathcal{O}=?$$

$$[\partial^{2}_{r},\frac{1}{\partial^{2}_{r}}]\mathcal{O}=?$$

Note: In the case of $\Box$ we know they do NOT commute. But is this also true for partial derivative case? We know in some very specific form of $\mathcal{O}$ they do commute, but generally it seems they do not?

How one define $\Box^{-1}$,$\nabla^{-1}$ and etc in terms of integral? What would be the boundaries of the integral?

and $\mathcal{O}$ is an operator in general (one can define between scalar, vector, tensor) (the easiest is scalar of course).

Comment: Have you tried representing, say, $\nabla^2$ in terms of it's Fourier transform?

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: You will have to provide a definition for the "inverse" operators for this to make sense. I see no natural notion for this, but there could be one. Note that, for "ordinary" operators, $[A,A^{-1}] = 1 - 1 = 0$.

Comment: It defined as an integral @ACuriousMind

Comment: You mean, the integral such that $\int \nabla \mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}$? That's not a local operation, so I am not sure if it can act on arbitrary operators $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: well what I mean is to take for instance $$\Box=-\partial^{2}_{t}$$ then $$\Box^{-1}f(t)=-\int^{t}_{t_*}\int^{t'}_{t_*}dt'dt''f(t'')$$

Comment: These things should always be considered inside an inner product, so for instance, $\int\!dx\, \phi^*(x)  \partial_x \psi(x)$, which you can Fourier transform to $\int\! dp\, \phi^*(p) i p\, \psi(p)$. It is usual to "evaluate" $\frac{1}{\partial_x^2}$ in momentum space, where it is equal to $-\frac{1}{p^2}$. You can do the commutator in momentum space then.

The only thing you need to assume, really, is that $\mathcal{O}\psi(x)$ is in $L^2$, I believe.

Comment: Suppose this is correct then say we have the following $$a(\partial^{2}_{r}
)\partial^{2}_{r}\Psi(r)=\delta^{3}(\bar{r})$$ in this case I can write $\partial^{2}_{r}$ as $-p^2$ because I am taking the Fourier transform but what about the following case? $$\frac{\partial^{2}_{r}\Phi}{\partial^{2}_{r}}$$ shall I simply take the partial derivative to momentum and cancel them out?!

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1130285/11127

Answer (score 3):

The inverse operators are Green's functions, this is rather common notation for them. For example, $\square^{-1}$ is the Green's function for the Klein-Gordon operator $\square$. Of course, boundary conditions (or a pole prescription) must be imposed in order to find a unique inverse (Green's function), so such a choice is implicit in this notation.

Often a slightly different version of this notation appears with the symbols indexed by their argument. For example, $\square_x$ indicates that this operator is acting w.r.t. the x-argument, and $\square^{-1}_{xy}$ indicates that the Green's function depends on the two coordinates, $x$, and $y$ (recall that Green's functions depend on two arguments).

In order to answer your question, I think one would need to know what is meant by $\square^{-1} \mathcal{O}$. In my experience these equations are always written in an explicit representation. For example, in the position space representation, this would be written as $\square_{xy}^{-1}\varphi_y$, and the double contraction over the $y$ coordinate would indicate that an integral is being preformed, where $\varphi_y$ is a quantum field evaluated at the point $y$. Can you provide an example where you run into this notation?

Comment: Thanks. I know the relation between $\Box$ and the Green function indeed as you just mentioned. My question was in general on any arbitrary operator. But to simplify the problem lets only consider the $$\Box^{-1}\Phi(r)\rightarrow \partial^{-2}_{r}\Phi(r)$$ the complete form is $$\frac{\partial_{r}^{2}\Phi(r)}{\partial_{r}^{2}}$$ now it is obvious that if the partial derivatives commute that will be equal to $\Phi(r)$ but if not which operation comes first? Shall one uses the green function still in this case (even though this is not complete $box$? or shall one go to momentum space?

Comment: Well first of all, $\square \neq \partial_r^2$. The spherical Laplacian is $\square = \partial_r^2 + \frac{2}{r} \partial_r$. Secondly, in order to evaluate this you need the Green's function, symbolically manipulating the symbols won't give the answer. Also, it's misleading to write the Green's function as $\partial_r^{-2}$ because as I said it has two arguments. I think if you write out the actual Green's function this equation will make more sense.

Comment: Then again Green function is for actual $\Box$ and in this specific case that I am working on the $\Box$ reduces to the partial derivative that is why I have used the arrow not the equal sign. Now the question is can one uses still use green function to calculate the inverse partial derivative? perhaps no?!